# Increment each object's value by 11 inside a list

Tags: java, object, operators

I have a list of objects where list name is employments and it has 'n' number of objects called employments.Each employment object has variable called serialnumber. Now i need to increment serialnumber for each object by 11.

Here is code

```
for(Employment employment:employments.getEmployemnts()){
  if(employment="GENERAL_MANAGER"){
    employement.setSerialNumberForGenManager()
  }else{
    employment.setSerialNumberForOthers()
  }
```

Inside the `employment` class:

```
public static employemntIndex=11;

public employemnt setSerialNumberForGenManager(){
this.serialNumber = 0;
}

public employemnt setSerialNumberForOthers(){
this.serialNumber = employemntIndex+serialNumber;
}
```

Now,i'm not able to increment values by 11. The result for every object is always 11 only.It is not getting incremented.

Comment: First of all, you can't compare between `Employment` object and `String` object; Second, to compare you need to use `==` and not `=`; And third, what is the initial value of `this.serialNumber` for each element before the loop runs?

Comment: it is zero before loop for each object

Comment: So I'm confused. If it's 0 and you add 11, why wouldn't they all be 11?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because of your String comparison. String comparisons should use the `Object#equals(Object)` method (as opposed to `==`);

```
if (yourString.equals("COMPARISON STRING")) //do stuff
```

This is because String is an instance (which happens to contain text), and the the `==` operator in this case only tests the references, not whether the instances themselves contain the same text.

Also, `=` is an assignment operator, `==` should be used for most comparisons (other than 'special cases', such as comparing Strings).

The next problem is that you are not carrying the values over (as you say). To fix this;

```
public static employemntIndex = 11;

//Increase the employment index for each GENERAL_MANAGER
public employemnt setSerialNumberForOthers(){
   this.serialNumber = employmentIndex;
   employmentIndex += 11;
}
```

Comment: I chnaged it. to equlas mtd .Even aftr this,it gives me result of 11,22 only.

Comment: I have this serialNumber variable for each applicant.This is int value .so by deault it wiuld be zero.I think the incremented value is not retained when we pass this value to next applicant.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see. I think I was also misunderstanding what you were trying to do. I will edit my answer to account for this.

Comment: @divya you should rename your variable emoloymentIndex to something like lastEmploymentIdxAssigned...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    public static Integer employemntIndex = 0;

    public employemnt setSerialNumberForOthers(){
        this.serialNumber = employemntIndex;
        employemntIndex += 11;
    }
```

Comment: @divya can you update the code how you are creating objects

Comment: it is the same code except for employment object has variable declared as public int serialNumber.

Comment: Also when i enter setSerialNumberForOthers() mtd each time,the incremented value for employemntIndex is not retained.Instead its value is zero each time i enter the loop

Comment: @divya How you are creating objects and adding to employments list

Comment: I have employemnt object class where i declare the variable  - public int serialNumber. then now in this mtd only i set the value for the employemnt object

Comment: I have this serialNumber variable for each applicant.I think this value is not retained when we pass this value to next applicant.But I didnt initailise this value to zero anywhere in my code

Comment: @divya The above code will work . I don't know where you are missing the logic. So only I asked the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible errors:

1. You are using a so called "enhanced for loop".

   You can't edit the elements of a collection that way as that loop is read-only.

   To edit elements you have to use a for loop with an explicit iteration index or an iterator.
2. You seem to be comparing a reference (memory address with a String that is unlikely to correspond to a memory address.

   ```
   employment="GENERAL_MANAGER"
   ```

   You probably forgot to call a getter method like

   ```
   employment.getRole().equals("GENERAL_MANAGER")
   ```

So it would be (if size() method is not supported you should use array.length)

```
for(int i = 0; i < employments.getEmployemnts().size(); i++) {
if(employments[i].yourGetter().equals("GENERAL_MANAGER")){
    employements[i].setSerialNumberForGenManager()
}else{
    employments[i].setSerialNumberForOthers()
}
```

Or if your collection implements the List interface

```
Iterator iter = employments.getEmployments().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()){
    Employment employment = iter.next();
    if(employment.yourGetter().equals("GENERAL_MANAGER")){
    employement.setSerialNumberForGenManager()
    }else{
        employment.setSerialNumberForOthers()
    }
}
```

Hope that helped

Edit:
as KookieMonster has noticed you are using the assignment operator within the IF condition you should use the equals method

Comment: Im not able   to use employment.setSerialNumberForOthers() this directly.beacuse my for loop implementation has changed.I want to call  setSerialNumberForGenManager mtd for the employement

Comment: Please post the whole Employment class. A note: from the name of your methods ...setForManager() ...setForOthers() it looks like you have picked a bad class design approach. You should use subclasses, but please go on and post your code so we can have a look at it

Comment: What is your desired output and what error do you get?

Comment: @divya I edited my answer: I forgot to add the i index within the for loop. Let me know how it goes